# Code Runner in VS Code Not Running Conda Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, anaconda3, vscode-code-runner

I've installed conda and want Code Runner's output to use the conda installation of Python.
When I run this code, this is the output I get:

[image]

It seems like Code Runner is using the non-conda Python, where I don't have the numpy package installed. The interpreter is set to conda. How do I get Code Runner to use conda's Python interpreter? Will adding conda to PATH help?

Alternatively, does anyone have a code runner extension that works better with conda? Thank you so much!

Comment: change python interpreter to conda, https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Comment: It still doesn't work. The interpreter is already switched to conda, but Code Runner is not using conda, for some reason.

Comment: Did you added python extension, changed interpreter and changed environment.

Comment: Python extension is added, interpreter is changed--bottom of blue bar reads 3.9.12('base': conda)--and I believe the base environment is being used.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it many times and found that **Code Runner** doesn't seem to follow the interpreter in the lower right corner. It picks the interpreter in your current environment, which seems to be the problem.

For example, if I use the **conda** environment now, no matter what interpreter I choose in the lower right corner, when I use **Code Runner** to run the code, it will use the interpreter in the conda environment, and it will not change with the lower right corner. Of course, everything is normal when you select run python file in the upper right corner to run the code (it will change accordingly).

So please make sure that the `numpy` package has been installed in your current environment. You can use `pip show numpy` in the **terminal** to see if the `numpy` package is installed and where it is installed.

*The following simple example demonstrates:*

**python code:**

```
import sys
import numpy as np

print('Current Python interpreter path: ' + sys.executable)

print("hello world")

a = np.arange(1,10,1)
print(a)
```

The `numpy` package is installed in my **conda** environment:

[image]

Select the conda interpreter, and the results of `Run Python File` and `Run Code` are the same:

[image]

`Run Python File`:

[image]

`Run Code`:

[image]

Select another python interpreter, then `Run Python File` switches the interpreter to run and reports an error:

[image]

`Run Code` still uses the conda interpreter and runs normally:

[image]

Uninstall the `numpy` package, no matter which interpreter reports an error:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the thorough reply! I have a couple questions: 

- I noticed you're using PowerShell; VS Code's PowerShell shows me:

 "conda : The term 'conda' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify 
that the path is correct and try again."

I'm forced to use Command Prompt. How did you get conda to be recognized in PS? 

- How do I verify the current environment I'm working on? I assume I've been using the conda environment (I do have another install of Python).

Comment: Additionally, my current Python interpreter path is located at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe.

Comment: In VS Code, when you switch between different python interpreters, you also switch between different working environments. So if you want to verify, just look at the interpreter path. After switching interpreters, you can choose to [create a new terminal](https://imgur.com/R60ntvw) and the command line will show you to activate the [new environment](https://imgur.com/a/xQYqQ2o).

Comment: Also, regarding your powershell not being able to use conda. Did you add the anaconda path in your system environment variables? About [conda installation](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/). About [using conda in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_create-a-conda-environment).

Comment: I haven't added conda to PATH; conda warns me that it can cause problems that may require you to uninstall and reinstall conda. Is this true?

Comment: The official documentation suggests that this may interfere with other software, but in my case it doesn't have any effect at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Click `Save Workspace As...` on the File menu (top-left) to create the `*.code-workspace` file.

Now when you open `vscode` it will prioritize the settings on this file over the default Json settings. Apply those settings (if you are using Code Runner extension) and it will work.

```
"settings": {
        "code-runner.executorMap": {
            "python": "C:\\Users\\<Your anaconda environment full path>\\python.exe"
        },
        "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "C:\\Users\\<Your anaconda environment full path>\\python.exe",
    }
```